# How to search certain lines in many texts in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have many texts in a folder and the texts contain the following format

```
#version = 11111
#version = 11112
#version = 11113
#version = 11114
version = 11115
```

#version is the previous version and  version is the newest

I want to find out the line of the newest version(11115) and its lastest version(11114) and list them in another text.

And I have used foreach and glob to find out all the texts
but I don't know how to  set (version = 11115)line n and the (#version = 11114) line n-1 (or other ways to find out this two lines)

I dont know how to express previous version.

```
foreach fileName [glob /aaatools/N*/release/version] {
set fp [open $fileName "r"]
while { [gets $fp data]>=0 } {
   {[regexp {set [^version =/]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*} $Version] | [regexp {set ??? } $previous_version] } {
        set information [$fileName] [$Version] [$previous_version]
        set fp2 [open "tool_version" w+]
        puts $fp2 $information
```

Comment: Post the code you are using and specify what's not working

Comment: I have posted my code .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have a text file structured like that, you can extract the information you are looking for fairly simply. The key trick is to use `regexp` to both *match* the line and *extract* the interesting part. And you are advised to use a temporary variable to capture the interesting part so that non-interesting lines don't overwrite. (This is more important when there are other, extra conditions on whether a value should be accepted.)

```
set current ""
set previous ""

set f [open $theTextFile]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach line $lines {
    if {[regexp {^\s*#\s*version\s+=\s+(\d+)} $line -> val]} {
        set previous $val
    } elseif {[regexp {^\s*version\s+=\s+(\d+)} $line -> val]} {
        if {$current ne ""} {
            puts stderr "WARNING: $theTextFile has multiple current versions: $current, $val"
        }
        set current $val
    }
}

# Show what we've found
puts "current = $current"
puts "previous = $previous"
```

Note that this assumes that you're interested in the *last* matching line in each case.

This only scans a single file. If you're working with multiple files, the easiest thing to do is to convert the above code into a procedure and then call it from a loop over the input filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use `lsearch` to find the line with the current version:

```
set f_out [open "tool_version" w+]
foreach file [glob ...] {
    set f_in [open $file r]
    set lines [split [read $f_in] \n]
    close $f_in

    # find the index of the line with the current version
    set idx [lsearch -regexp $lines {^version *=}]
    regexp {version\s*=\s*(\d+)} [lindex $lines $idx] -> current_version
    # index arithmetic .............................vv
    regexp {version\s*=\s*(\d+)} [lindex $lines $idx-1] -> prev_version

    puts $f_out [list $file $current_version $prev_version]
}
close $f_out
```

Note that `->` in the regexp commands has no special meaning: it's just a dummy variable name that stores the complete text matching the pattern. It has become idiomatic.

---

A couple of things to mention about the code you posted:

```
   {[regexp {set [^version =/]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*} $Version] | [regexp {set ??? } $previous_version] } {
```

- missing `if`
- the first argument to `regexp` is a [regular expression](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), so "set" in there is part of the pattern.
- `|` is the bitwise-or operator: you want the `||` boolean or operator. Ref [`expr`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm)

Comment: thanks for help!! but I can't regexp the correct version . My version format is 10.10-n2_1  ,I think this is a problem. Also $filename is not defined.

Comment: The version format is the kind of information that needs to be in your question.